# ModuleNotFoundError for Python import of file that imports neighboring files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, filepath

I am having an issue importing a file that imports other files. My folder structure looks as follows:

**Folder Structure:**

```
proj/
    src/
        main_script.py
        some_module/
            module-file.py
            helper_a.py
            helper_b.py
            helper_c.py
```

Each of the files contain this

**proj/src/main_script.py:**

```
import module_file as mf
```

**proj/src/some_module/module_file.py:**

```
import helper_a
import helper_b
import helper_c
```

When I run `main_script.py`, the import of `module_file.py` fails with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper_a'
```

If I were to set `some_module` as my working directory, this wouldn't be an issue, but the relative paths aren't working from the src directory. I tried adding a `__init__.py` file to the `some_module` folder, but that didn't affect the outcome. Any insight on how this is supposed to work would be appreciated.

Comment: You may find help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Furthermore, you should replace the `-` or use `__import__()`

Comment: I meant to use those as examples. This issue persists without the hyphens as well

Answer (score 0):

main_script.py

```
from some_module.module_file import * as mf
```

main_file.py

```
from helper_a import *
from helper_b import *
from helper_c import *
```

Comment: You must convert the hyphens to underscore as mentioned by Diego Torres Milano in the above comment

Comment: Sorry I meant to use those as place holder. I run into this error without hyphens